# Intellij set module compile output as library

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I was wondering if this was possible in IntelliJ

I have 3 modules (Client, Server, and Protocol). My current way of doing things is to compile the Protocol module as a jar, and then use it as a library in my Client & Server module. However, this means that I have to refresh IntelliJ each time.

Is there a way for me to add a module as a library directly to my Server and Client modules? I have already tried going into libraries and adding the src/ folder for Protocol to my Client and Server modules.

I also looked at http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/configuring-module-dependencies-and-libraries.html but couldn't get an answer.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried this:

- **Project Structure**  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> (for Windows) or **File - Project Structure**
- **Modules** (on LHS)
- You should now see 3 modules in the middle list (provided you have set up the modules)
- Select the module to add a dependency to
- **Dependencies Tab** (Top Middle)
- Click **+** symbol on RHS to add a dependency
- Select **Module Dependency**
- Choose the module which it depends on.

This requires that all 3 modules are set up within the same project.